# Javascript Map Function

Tags: javascript

This question is from the JavaScript [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/bm/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) -

```js
var elements = [
  'Helium',
  'Oxygen',
  'Lithium',
  'Beryllium'
];

console.log(elements.map(({ length }) => length));

// Output - [6, 6, 7, 9]
```

I am not able to understand How is it able to calculate length of each elements from the array? I mean how this syntax works?

Comment: The reason is: `Destructuring assignment` of `es2015`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're using in your code is called *[destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)* and it allows you to use directly desired properties of an object.

```
console.log(elements.map(( {length} ) => length));
```

is equivalent to

```
console.log(elements.map(str => str.length));
```

```js
var elements = [
    'Helium',
    'Oxygen',
    'Lithium',
    'Beryllium'
];

console.log(elements.map(str => str.length));
```

Answer (score 1):

Length of a string is available as a string property `length`:

```js
console.log('test'.length);
```

In your code, you iterate thru array of strings and do `elements.map(( {length} ) => length)`. That is a short version of this:

```js
var elements = [
    'Helium',
    'Oxygen',
    'Lithium',
    'Beryllium'
];

console.log(elements.map(item => item.length));
```

This is called object destructing:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(elements.map(( {length} ) => length));
```

is the same as:

```
console.log(elements.map(str => str.length));
```

is the same as:

```
console.log(elements.map(function(el){return el.length;}));
```

Here is how the map function works:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: TheSmith - Thank You So much. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> The [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.

Since the each array items are of type string thus has the *length* property which is actually returned.

```js
var elements = [
    'Helium',
    'Oxygen',
    5, // has no length property
    'Beryllium'
];

console.log(elements.map(str => str.length));
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what's your purpose for this snippet, but if you want to map an array like this you could do something like below:
Copying your code

```js
var elements = [
  'Helium',
  'Oxygen',
  'Lithium',
  'Beryllium'
];

elements.map(item=>{console.log(item)});

/* Output: 
  Helium,
  Oxygen,
  Lithium,
  Beryllium*/
```

Comment: she's not asking about how loop ?

Answer (score 0):

so basically what `map` function does is it maps every single element of it

`forEach()` — executes a provided function once for each array element.

`map()` — creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```
arr.forEach((num, index) => {
    return arr[index] = num * 2;
});

let doubled = arr.map(num => {
    return num * 2;
});
```

output for both is same //[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

for more details refer [this](https://codeburst.io/javascript-map-vs-foreach-f38111822c0f)